# Melhor forma de realizar builds complexo

Tags: c#, visual-studio, build

Tenho uma aplicação que carrega dinamicamente dlls e outros componentes em tempo de execução, e estou em busca de uma solução para montar builds "complexos" no estilo do Apache Ant (disponível no Java). Quais opções eu tenho? Alguma sugestão?

Comment: O MSBuild padrão do Visual Studio não te atende? Existe o Nant, mas hoje acho que ele ficou bem pra trás. Cake, Nuke, Cruise Control, teamCity,

Comment: Como o @Maniero mencionou, se ainda não usou o MSBuild deveria dar uma olhada, aqui usamos e fazemos builds com muitas particularidades, além de publicar no servidor, para aplicação, serviço, *App Pool*, etc. [Aqui uma boa leitura do MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dd393573.aspx)

Comment: Nunca utilizei o msbuild, pelo que li dos links mencionados irá me atender. muito obrigado pela dica :)